# Onscroll setstate triggering re render in section list pure component

Tags: react-native, expo, onscroll, react-native-sectionlist

Hi All im working with a section list with collapsible headers and I'm using a onscroll trigger on section list to pop up a bottom navbar after an offset of 200

Everything works fine but the setstate in my onscroll is causing a re render of my section list  even though its a pure component which inturn gives me the error

```
VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc.
```

Here is the [expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@nick17728/sectionlistissue), i have added a console logs in  menusSectionList.js file ,Any advice would be really helpful